# Replace and update IDs using JavaScript stored procedure

Tags: javascript, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

**Background:**

I need to create a stored procedure in JavaScript (within CosmosDB) where: For every Feedback document, replace/update Feedback.id with new id

```
var NewID = "5678"

{

"Feedbacks" : [
 {
    "id": "1234"
 }
 {
    "id": "1234"
 }  
] 

}
```

**This is what I am doing:**

I have created a function called UpdateID and set the parameters to OldID and NewID. I am saying iterate through the document, and for every OldID value,, replace with the NewID. I am moreso familiar with Python so this is a bit different for me and I am not sure this is the correct approach.

```
For every iteration in doc.Feedbacks:

function UpdateID(OldID, NewID) {

     if (Feedbacks.id = "OldID") 
     
     

}
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Where is your new id stored for feedbacks?

Comment: It is in the output of a LogicApp. It is stored within a variable that the LogicApp has created

Comment: It looks like there's a lot of information here that you need to keep private, is there someone on your team that you can get help from? Unfortunately this question is far too vague to get any sort of reasonable answer.

Comment: Not at the time. Let me re phrase it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to write the javascript, but here's one way that should get on the right track:

```
function UpdateID(oldID, newID) {
    //get just the records that need updating
    var isAccepted = __.filter(
        function(doc) { 
            return doc.Feedbacks && doc.Feedbacks.findIndex(function(feedback){
                return feedback.id == oldID
            }) > -1;
        },
        function (err, feed, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found'
            if (!feed || !feed.length) {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody('no docs found');
            }
            else {
                //update the documents that have the old id
                UpdateDoc(oldID, newID, feed)
            }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}

//function based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009939/documentdb-updating-multiple-documents-fails
function UpdateDoc(oldID, newID, documents) {
    console.log("updating " + documents.length + " docs")
    if (documents.length > 0) {
        var document = documents[0];

        // DocumentDB supports optimistic concurrency control via HTTP ETag.
        var requestOptions = { etag: document._etag};

        document.Feedbacks =  document.Feedbacks.map(function(feedback){
            if(feedback.id === oldID) {
                feedback.id = newID;
            }

            return feedback;
        });

        // Update the document.
        var isAccepted = __.replaceDocument(document._self, document, requestOptions, function(err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
           if (err) {
              responseBody.error = err;
              throw err;
           }
        });

        // If we hit execution bounds - throw an exception.
        if (!isAccepted) {
            responseBody.log += "Update not accepted";
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
        else {
            documents.shift();
            if(documents.length > 0){
                UpdateDoc(oldID, newID, documents);
            }
        }
    }
}
```